# how to represent map in mermaid?

Tags: c++, mermaid

I am using mermaid to create a UML diagram. I need to represent

```
map<int,std::string> pMap;
```

How do I achieve this?
I tried

```
std::map~int,string~ vpuParamMap;
```

It resulted in a crash.

Comment: This sounds like you wanted to file a bug report with the [mermaid project](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The normal characters didn't work for me either, but as a workaround the HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` are usable:

```
std::map&lt;int, std::string&gt; vpuParamMap
```

which should result in

```
std::map<int, std::string> vpuParamMap
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the space after the `>` or `<`

Took your case, in a classDiagram :

```
classDiagram
class stuff {
  map< int,std::string > pMap;
}
```

Gives :

[image: classdiagram]